# I want to show the quiz question and option from the Firebase database. However, I am getting the error. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Flutter. I am trying to develop an application.

I want to show the quiz question and option from the Firebase database.

What is wrong with my code?

Help me somebody who is used to Flutter and Firebase.

```
class _PlayQuizState extends State<PlayQuiz> {
  DatabaseService databaseService = DatabaseService();
   late QuerySnapshot questionsnapshot;
  Questions getquestionsfromsnapshot(DocumentSnapshot questionsnapshot){
  Questions questions= Questions();
  questions.question=questionsnapshot.data["question"]; //this is where i am getting error//
  List<String> Options = [
      questionsnapshot.data["Option1"],//this is where i am getting error//
      questionsnapshot.data["Option2"],//this is where i am getting error//
      questionsnapshot.data["Option3"],//this is where i am getting error//
      questionsnapshot.data["Option4"]//this is where i am getting error//
    ];
  
}
```

## I am getting the following error.

- The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'.
  Try defining the operator '[]'

Comment: share your firebase DB image

Comment: `questionsnapshot.data` should be `questionsnapshot.data()!` I think (after checking it is not `null`), but you have to pay attention: data is almost surely fetched as a `Future`, so you might need a `FutureBuilder` here.